# Shift_JISX0213 (Shift_JIS_2004) はどこで使われていますか？

Tags: 文字化け, 文字コード, shift-jis

Python やそのほかのプログラミング言語、プラットフォームで、Shift_JIS っぽい日本語のデータをデコードするのに失敗した人たちが、文字エンコーディングとして Shift_JISX0213 や Shift_JIS-2004 を指定すると読める、というノウハウを公開しています。

しかしもし Windows 由来のデータを Shift_JIS X 0213 系の文字コードとして読んでしまうとバックスラッシュ `\` `0x5c`, たちさき `﨑` `0xfa0xb1`, はしごだか `髙` `0xfb0xfc` がそれぞれ `¥` `U+00A5`, `郫`, `騠` に文字化けします。

自分のブログに、その文字コードを使うのはほぼ誤解であり、[正しくは cp932 (ms932) であると書いた](https://criticabug.hatenablog.com/entry/python-cp932) のですが、はっきりさせたくなりました。

実際に誤解ではなく Shift_JIS X 0213 系の文字コードを使うシステムはあるのでしょうか？ ブラウザはほぼ対応していないです。

2010年の本『プログラマのための文字コード技術入門』（矢野啓介）では適した用途として

> Shift_JIS-2004 は Shift_JIS の資産と互換性を保ちつつ JIS X 0213 に対応するのに適した符号化方式です。（…中略…）今後は、Shift_JIS というときにもっぱら Shift_JIS-2004 を用いるという手もあります。

と、可能性が示唆されている感じでした。

Comment: Windows上で実行するかどうかではなく、「Windows 由来のデータ」その文字化けについて議論するならWindowsに関係があるのでは？

Comment: 前振りを書いたせいで勘違いが起こりやすいのかもしれませんが、知りたいのは Shift_JIS X0213 を採用して運用しているシステムやアプリケーションがあるか、です。もしいるなら無条件で「Shift_JIS X 0213 使うな。間違いだ」とは言えないな、とか思ったので。

Comment: もしかして、文字化けタグとも無関係な質問ですか？ 質問文が色々と誤解を与えていて、答えて欲しい内容を聞けていないように見受けられます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift_JIS-2004はIANAの[Character sets](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml)にも登録されていませんし、UNICODEの[MAPPINGS](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/)にもありません。標準で使っているようなシステムはたぶん**存在しない**と思われます。

以下Shfit_JISとその亜種や拡張を標準で採用しているシステムと対応言語をまとめました。

- Shift_JIS **IANA登録あり** [UNICODEマッピング](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/JIS/SHIFTJIS.TXT)
  言語: Java(Shift_JIS), Python(shift_jis), PHP(SJIS), Ruby(Shift_JIS)
- Shift_JISX0213
  言語: Python(shift_jisx0213)
- Shift_JIS-2004
  言語: Python(shift_jis_2004)
- Windows-31J **IANA登録あり** [UNICODEマッピング](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP932.TXT)
  システム: Windows
  言語: Java(windows-31j), .NET(shift_jis), Python(cp932), PHP(SJIS-win), Ruby(Windows-31J)
- MacJapanese [UNICODEマッピング](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/JAPANESE.TXT)
  システム: Mac OS 9以前
  言語: .NET(x-mac-japanese), PHP(SJIS-mac), Ruby(MacJapanese)
- SJIS-DoCoMo
  システム: ドコモの携帯電話
  言語: PHP(SJIS-Mobile#DOCOMO), Ruby(SJIS-DoCoMo)
- SJIS-KDDI
  システム: auの携帯電話
  言語: PHP(SJIS-Mobile#KDDI), Ruby(SJIS-KDDI)
- SJIS-SoftBank
  システム: ソフトバンクの携帯電話
  言語: PHP(SJIS-Mobile#SOFTBANK), Ruby(SJIS-SoftBank)

各言語は下記リンク先を参考にしています。
[Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/intl/supported-encodings.html), [.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=netframework-4.8),[Python](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.8/library/codecs.html), [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/mbstring.supported-encodings.php), [Ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Encoding.html)

各携帯電話会社のSJIS拡張は絵文字用でしたが、Unicodeへの絵文字追加によってスマートフォンでは直接Unicode(UTF-8)でやり取りしているようです。

上のリストの「システム」はデフォルト設定でその文字コードになることがあるということです。わざわざ選択した場合、例えば、Mac OS X以降のテキストエディットで日本語(Mac)を選ぶとMacJapaneseになったりします。他にも、LinuxでもShift_JISをデフォルトロケールに設定することもできます。しかし、それらをわざわざ使う人はいないと思われます。

---

OS等では対応していなくても、文字コードをよく理解していないプログラマーが作ったシステムであれば、Shift_JIS-2004を使ってしまっている可能性はあります。たとえば、次のようなシナリオです。

1. とあるデータ(名称などに漢字が含まれている)を分析するPythonのプログラムを作ることになった。
2. 分析結果の表を「Excelで読み込めるようにシフトジスのCSVファイルでデータを出力してくれ」と依頼された。
3. 文字コードを"shift_jis"に設定して出力するようにした。
4. その後のテストで一部の文字がエラーになることがわかった。JISX2013で追加された文字だったので、より大きい領域を持つ"shift_jis-2004"に設定しなおした。

こうして、エラーも起きなかったのでそのままプログラムを納品してしまい、後ほど、Excelで見ると文字化けしている、違う文字になっているとクレームが入ることになるでしょう(日本語版のExcelはBOMが無いとWindows-31Jで解釈します)。「シフトジス」という言葉はShift_JISなのか、Windows-31Jなのか、はたまた、MacJapaneseなのかを理解していない人は多いので、誰かが作ったシステムから出力されたファイルであれば、その人にちゃんと確認しておいた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: 絵文字の亜種までまとめて、ありがとうございます。私もHTML取り込みで似たシナリオの処理に行き当たりました。文字化けを人知れず生み続けるこのミスは逐一指摘していきたいと、あらためて思います。

Answer (score 5):

> Windows 由来のデータを Shift_JIS X 0213 系の文字コードとして読んでしまうと（中略）文字化けします。

おっしゃる通りです。Windowsでは[JIS X 0213](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0213)に対応していますが、それは文字集合としてのJIS X 0213が収録されているUnicode3.1以降に対応しているという意味で、符号化としての[Shift_JIS-2004](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS-2004)エンコーディングには対応していません。
具体的には、Shift_JIS-2004の第3水準漢字、第4水準漢字部分は[NEC選定IBM拡張文字およびIBM拡張文字](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8932#Windows-31J_%E3%81%AB%E9%87%8D%E8%A4%87%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)とバッティングします。

ですので、Windowsが扱うShift-JIS的エンコーディングはcp932(ms932)で間違いないです。またWindowsとのやりとりでJIS X 0213を扱いたいのであればUTF-8などUnicodeを使用する必要があります。

Comment: 質問者としてはこれは特に回答になっていないと感じます

Answer (score 0):

MSでないSJIS X 213で入力されたならMSでないSJIS X 213で読み取り、
MS932で入力されたならMS932で読み取ります。

あなたが読み取ろうとしているデータがどこからどう入力されたかの仕様を調べてください。
一般的に、
Windowsで使用されるアプリケーション全般でsjisで保存とあれば実際にはMS932ですし、
Macや<s>iPhone</s>のアプリケーション全般でsjisを指定したなら、それはsjis 2004です。
ただし、実際には個々のアプリケーションの実装に依存します。

追記
iPhoneアプリ作成時に使用する典型的なSwiftやObjective-Cでは、0x80000A01を指定しないとCP932でないSJISを得られないみたいですね。かなり少ないことが予想されます。

Comment: 質問の趣旨が `実際に誤解ではなく Shift_JIS X 0213 系の文字コードを使うシステムはあるのでしょうか？` ということですので、回答になっていないように思います。

Comment: “_読み取ろうとしているデータがどこからどう入力されたかの仕様を調べ_” るのは賛成なのですが、 “_MacやiPhoneのアプリケーション全般でsjisを指定したなら、それはsjis 2004_” は本当ですか？ 今 charset=Shift_JIS であるページ http://charset.7jp.net/sjis.html を iOS 12 と macOS High Sierra の Safari で見てみても、Windows の Edge と同じで、つまり Safari では Shift_JIS は CP932 もしくは MS932 のエイリアスです。

Comment: Windowsのメモ帳はCP932のテキストを出力できますし、Macのテキストエディットのフォーマットでデフォルトでチェックの入っているShift JISはCP932ではないと思います。…で、この回答はそもそも質問者が欲しい回答ではないと思っているので書かなかったです。（知りたいのはdjangoの入力データの文字コードってなんやねん！とかそっち系だと思いますし…）で、こうなってくるとブラウザからの入力内容なの？それとも独自システムのAPIの入力内容なの？とか個別実装の話になってしまうので、そもそもそこを明らかにする以外に現実的な回答はできないよねーと思ってます。

Comment: どう勘違いされているのか分からないんですが、知りたいのは Shift_JIS X0213 を採用して運用している個別実装があるか、です。私がいま文字化けで苦しんでいるわけではないです。

Comment: 勘違いしていました。ブログも見ましたが、つまり「Shift_JIS X 213(CP932ではない X213拡張文字コード系）を使用しているシステムはMac OS のSafari以外に何がありますか？」という質問だったということですね。ちなみに私は1度もないです。

Comment: @criticabug 氏のコメントによると、 ` Safari では Shift_JIS は CP932 もしくは MS932 のエイリアスです。` とのことですので、SafariでもShift_JIS-2004ではないと結論しているようです。

Comment: @PicoSushiさん、ありがとうございます…ほんとだ…。@criticabugさん、ブログでは「例えばブラウザでも macOS 版 Safari が Shift_JIS_X0213-2000 に対応しているのみです。」と書いてありますが、少なくとも macOS High SierraではCP932系になっているということでしょうか？

Comment: @PicoSushi @takemori_kondo 確かめてないのですが `charset=Shift_JIS_X0213-2000` と指定したりメニューから Japanese (Shift JIS X0213) 選ぶと使えるようです.

Answer (score 0):

プログラミング言語 Gauche では [sjis を Shift_JIS X 0213 と定義している](http://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/?l=ja&p=%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97) ので、Gauche で組まれたシステムでは（知ってか知らずか）Shift_JIS X 0213 を入出力している可能性があります。